# django-admin ImportError: No module named server_conf.settings.settings_devel_local

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

I installed django on a virtual environment on mac OSX, but when I tried to run "django-admin startproject mysite," I get the following import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/me/djangodjango/ENV/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())

File "/Users/me/djangodjango/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()

File "/Users/me/djangodjango/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
settings.INSTALLED_APPS

File "/Users/me/djangodjango/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)

File "/Users/me/djangodjango/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)

File "/Users/me/djangodjango/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)

ImportError: No module named server_conf.settings.settings_devel_local
```

I get the same error if I try "django-admin help." Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: do you have all the `__init__.py` files present ?

Comment: Yes, I was able to find all the files referenced in the trace.